# DateTime from date and time picker

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a date and time picker:

```
Future<void> _showDatePicker(BuildContext context) async {
      final picked = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: _fromDate,
        firstDate: DateTime(1000, 1),
        lastDate: DateTime(2200),
      );
      print(picked);
      if (picked != null && picked != _fromDate) {
        setState(() {
          _fromDate = picked;
        });
      }
    }

    Future<void> _showTimePicker(BuildContext context) async {
      final picked = await showTimePicker(
        context: context,
        initialTime: _fromTime,
      );
      print(picked);
      if (picked != null && picked != _fromTime) {
        setState(() {
          _fromTime = picked;
        });
      }
    }
```

When I pick a date, the result is `2021-03-10 00:00:00.000` and when I pick a time, the result is `TimeOfDay(22:12)`.

How do I combine both of them to have `2021-03-10 22:12:00.000`. That's what I want to save to my database.

And how do I remove the three trailing zeros from the date `2021-03-10 00:00:00.000` of so it can look like this --> `2021-03-10 00:00:00` when displaying it in a `Text()` widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After selecting the date and time, you must generate a new datetime object in this way.

```
DateTime _fromDate = new DateTime.now();
TimeOfDay _fromTime = new TimeOfDay.now();

DateTime newDateTime = new DateTime(_fromDate.year, _fromDate.month,
    _fromDate.day, _fromTime.hour, _fromTime.minute);
```

Then use the [intl package](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) to format the date to the string you want.

```
String dateTimeFormated = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss').format(newDateTime);
print(dateTimeFormated);
```

Result will be a string similar to this

```
2021-03-10 22:12:00
```